# Conditional not giving expected answer

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm writing a pretty simple conditional that is only giving me the "else" answer.

The idea is that if I have more pets (pets) than my friend (friendsPets), then I need to assign it to a new variable (mostPets) to see who has the most pets.  But when I log the new variable (mostPets) it's only giving me the answer from the "else" part of the conditional.  The new variable should be logging 4 in the console, but it's only logging 0.  If I rearrange the conditional statements it does give me 4 - but I know that's not right.  I know this is a fairly simple problem, but I'm pretty new to this.  Any advice?

```js
let pets = 2;
let friendsPets = 0;
pets = 4;

if (pets > friendsPets) {
  let mostPets = pets
} else(friendsPets > pets)
let mostPets = friendsPets
console.log(mostPets);
```

Comment: `else if (friendsPets > pets)`  - and be consistent on the curly brackets and you can use  Math.max to shorten your code

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: You're going to want to declare `mostPets` outside the `if`/`else`.

Comment: variables declared with `let` only exist within the scope in which they were declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare your variable mostPets before doing the conditions, otherwise the variable won't be able to be accessed outside of that condition.

Also, your condition else-if was written incorrectly. With those changes it should work correctly like this:

```js
let pets = 2;
let friendsPets = 0;
pets = 4;

let mostPets;
if (pets > friendsPets) {
  mostPets = pets
} else if (friendsPets > pets) {
  mostPets = friendsPets
}
// Note in this scenario we are ignoring if the variables are the same value, it would be better to just put 'else' without an extra condition.
console.log(mostPets);
```

**Note:**
As mentioned by @mplungjan, to shorten your code you can change your logic with the following code to get the same result:

```
let mostPets = Math.max(pets, friendsPets);
```

Comment: Not only in the comments. I made it an answer

Comment: Yes!  It works great now,  Thanks so much for the help.  One more question:  why do I need to use "if else" and not just "else?"  I thought "if else" was only used if there were multiple options before the final "else" statement.

Comment: You can use only an `else` in this scenario, but in your question you had a condition, and in that statement you can't add conditions, so it would just be the opposite of your `if` the structure of this code would be `if (condition) { your code } else { your code }` check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/else-statement-javascript/) link for a further explanation

Answer (score 1):

You missed an if and you need to declare all the vars and not use let more than once. Let inside curly brackets is only visible in that so-called scope

You mention in a comment you need to use ifs, then If you were to remove the second condition, you do not need the second if:

```js
const pets = 2;
const friendsPets = 0;
let mostPets = pets; // default - could be 0 or nothing (undefined)

if (pets > friendsPets) {
  mostPets = pets;
} else {
  mostPets = friendsPets;
}
console.log(mostPets);

// OR using the ternary operator;

mostPets = pets > friendsPets ? pets : friendsPets;
console.log(mostPets);
```

Here is a more elegant version since you are comparing numbers

```js
const pets = 2;
const friendsPets = 0;
let mostPets = Math.max(pets,friendsPets)

console.log(mostPets);
```

Comment: That certainly works too, but this was for an assignment using conditionals.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @JamesPaulMolnar see my update explaining the need or no need for the second if